# A basic question on necessary and sufficient condition for positive recurrence

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains

If state $j$ is recurrent and the following holds can it be called as positive recurrent ?

$$\lim_{n -> \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}p_{jj}^{(k)} > 0$$

I know that this a necessary condition for positive recurrence, but is it sufficient ?

Comment: You should probably try your question on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I tried there but have not got any answer

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes. A good version of the ergodic theorem for Markov Chains says that for any discrete Markov chain, $\frac1{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1_{\{X_k=j\}}$ almost surely converges to $\frac{1_{T_j<+\infty}}{E^j[T_j]}$.
So, by dominated convergence, the quantity that you consider converges to

$\frac{P^j(T_j<+\infty)}{E^j[T_j]}$. If the limit is positive, $E^j[T_j]<+\infty$, which is precisely positive recurrence.